# Is it possible to set a default error page using Go on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, internal-server-error, panic

I've previously worked with J2EE where it's possible to add this configuration to `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

The effect of the above code is that if an unhanded exception is thrown, it will be passed to the `/error` page, which will be shown to the user.

Is there a way to do something similar to this when my Go web application panics on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see [Custom error responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses):

> When certain errors occur, App Engine serves a generic error page. You
>   can configure your app to serve a custom static file instead of these
>   generic error pages, so long as the custom error data is less than 10
>   kilobytes. You can set up different static files to be served for each
>   supported error code by specifying the files in your app's app.yaml
>   file. To serve custom error pages, add a error_handlers section to
>   your app.yaml, as in this example:
>
> ```
> error_handlers:
>   - file: default_error.html
>
>   - error_code: over_quota
>     file: over_quota.html
> ```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for